# run specific version of ruby script if command line argument is entered

Tags: ruby, argv, optparse

I've read through tons of variations of my question, but I can't seem to find one that really matches up with what I'm trying to do.

I have a script that essentially has two versions: the "default" would run through a series of mandatory methods, and the second version would run through those same methods, then tack on a series of secondary methods. I would like the second version to be triggered from the command line (something like `$ script.rb second_version`), and the "default" option to be triggered by no argument input at all (since it's going to be used more frequently, so just `$ script.rb`).

I tried this with ARGV:

```
second_version = ARGV[0]

if second_version
   second_version_methods
else
  main_version
end
```

This technically works, but the problem is that the very first method that runs in the main_version script is a method that requires user input. What ends up happening is that the string "second_version" is automatically passed to that method as the value, which I don't want.

Essentially, is there a way to have a command line argument that will *only* specify a condition to run in a particular way, and then once that's done, it just drops the input? I've looked into optparse but its functionality seems a bit superfluous for this purpose.

Thank you!

Comment: Still, you'll love optparse in a couple of months :) Honestly, as it behaves pretty predictably (and allows for better "arguments" like `--interactive` and `-i` together with a help text) as soon as you implement the third_version consider using it, although its pretty bureaucratic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ARGV` isn't readonly, so you could consume the first input like this:

```
if ARGV[0] == 'second_version'
  ARGV.shift # removes the first element 
  second_version_methods
else
  main_version
end
```

If you want to keep ARGV intact (which is a better idea), you can do this:

```
arguments = ARGV.dup

if arguments[0] == 'second_thing'
  arguments.shift
# ...
```

Comment: This is exactly what I've been looking for, thank you so much for such a concise and perfect response!

Comment: Happy to help! Don't forget to accept this as the answer.